# Files REST operations in Office 365

Tags: azure, office365, onedrive

A couple newbie questions.

1. Is it possible to use the Files REST APIs to integrate with OneDrive for Personal?
2. Looking through the Files REST API page - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/files-rest-operations, I don't seem see a way to create/update folder/file with permission(eg, create/update a file to be share-able etc).
3. If I don't want to use OpenID connect to handle the common consent form workflow(which is widely available in many if not all of their sample codes), anyone has any pointers to how this can be done otherwise?

Thanks in advance for any pointers!
RT

Answer (score 0):

1. The OneDrive for Business API's do not integrate with personal OneDrives at this point. There are other API's for that (http://msdn.microsoft.com/onedrive).
2. Unfortunately, the Files REST API does not yet support editing permissions.
3. Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but there are steps to manually integrate the consent flow at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/add-common-consent-manually. You still need to use OAuth 2.0 to integrate with OneDrive for Business.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  For your answer to #1 - Are you confirming that the Files REST APIs are designed for OneDrive for Business only? I bumped into an introductory course that was hosted by Jeremy Thake, I got the impression that the API should be supporting OneDrive for Personal in the GA of office 365 API.

Comment: Hi Ray. We're working to evolve both sets of API's, and we'd like to get to having a single dev experience for both OneDrive and OneDrive for Business. But today they have separate API's.